# Put a preexesting code of a JFrame in a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, jpanel

I have an existing Java code from JUNG library,
But i want to add me custom code to create a user interface.
I've created the user interface using the design tab on Netbeans IDE. But whene i add the custom code,
the swing elements can't seem to be put in the order iv'e designed.
I guess my problem lays in setting the proper `LAYOUT`

Here is the layout iv'e designed in Netbeans

[Image One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjHJY.jpg)

What i want is to add the following code to the `JPanel`
The problem is this code takes `JFrame` as an argument, but in my case i need to put it inside the `JPanel`

Here is the preexisting code i have and what it does in the following image:
[Image Two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQWca.jpg)

```
public class EditorMouse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Interface");
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        SparseMultigraph<GraphElements.MyVertex, GraphElements.MyEdge> g
                = new SparseMultigraph<GraphElements.MyVertex, GraphElements.MyEdge>();
        // Layout<V, E>, VisualizationViewer<V,E>
        // Map<GraphElements.MyVertex,Point2D> vertexLocations = new HashMap<GraphElements.MyVertex, Point2D>();
        Layout<GraphElements.MyVertex, GraphElements.MyEdge> layout = new StaticLayout(g);
        //layout.setSize(new Dimension(400, 350));
        VisualizationViewer<GraphElements.MyVertex, GraphElements.MyEdge> vv
                = new VisualizationViewer<GraphElements.MyVertex, GraphElements.MyEdge>(layout);
        vv.getRenderContext().setVertexLabelTransformer(new ToStringLabeller());
        vv.getRenderContext().setEdgeLabelTransformer(new ToStringLabeller());
        // Create a graph mouse and add it to the visualization viewer
        EditingModalGraphMouse gm = new EditingModalGraphMouse(vv.getRenderContext(),
                GraphElements.MyVertexFactory.getInstance(),
                GraphElements.MyEdgeFactory.getInstance());
        // Set some defaults for the Edges...
        GraphElements.MyEdgeFactory.setDefaultCapacity(10.0);
        GraphElements.MyEdgeFactory.setDefaultWeight(10.0);
        // Trying out our new popup menu mouse plugin...
        PopupVertexEdgeMenuMousePlugin myPlugin = new PopupVertexEdgeMenuMousePlugin();
        // Add some popup menus for the edges and vertices to our mouse plugin.
        JPopupMenu edgeMenu = new MyMouseMenus.EdgeMenu(frame);
        JPopupMenu vertexMenu = new MyMouseMenus.VertexMenu();
        myPlugin.setEdgePopup(edgeMenu);
        myPlugin.setVertexPopup(vertexMenu);
        gm.remove(gm.getPopupEditingPlugin());  // Removes the existing popup editing plugin
        gm.add(myPlugin);   // Add our new plugin to the mouse

        vv.setGraphMouse(gm);
        frame.getContentPane().add(vv);
        gm.setMode(ModalGraphMouse.Mode.EDITING); // Start off in editing mode
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Comment: You have to go the other way.  You can put a JPanel inside a JFrame.  You can't put a JFrame inside a panel.  JFrames are top-level components and they're special, they have to be at the root of your GUI hierarchy.

Comment: Yes, i understand that. But my preexisting code only allows me to use JFrame to add the graph elements to it.

Comment: Change your preexisting code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a VisualizationViewer extends JPanel , I would move the code that initializes it into its own class something like this:

```
public class MyVisualizationViewer extends VisualizationViewer<GraphElements.MyVertex, GraphElements.MyEdge> {
    public MyVisualizationViewer() {
        super(new StaticLayout(new SparseMultigraph<GraphElements.MyVertex, GraphElements.MyEdge>()));
        this.getRenderContext().setVertexLabelTransformer(new ToStringLabeller());
        this.getRenderContext().setEdgeLabelTransformer(new ToStringLabeller());
        // Create a graph mouse and add it to the visualization viewer
        EditingModalGraphMouse gm = new EditingModalGraphMouse(this.getRenderContext(),
                GraphElements.MyVertexFactory.getInstance(),
                GraphElements.MyEdgeFactory.getInstance());
        // Set some defaults for the Edges...
        GraphElements.MyEdgeFactory.setDefaultCapacity(10.0);
        GraphElements.MyEdgeFactory.setDefaultWeight(10.0);
//        // Trying out our new popup menu mouse plugin...
        PopupVertexEdgeMenuMousePlugin myPlugin = new PopupVertexEdgeMenuMousePlugin();
//        // Add some popup menus for the edges and vertices to our mouse plugin.
        JPopupMenu edgeMenu = new MyMouseMenus.EdgeMenu(frame);
        JPopupMenu vertexMenu = new MyMouseMenus.VertexMenu();
        myPlugin.setEdgePopup(edgeMenu);
        myPlugin.setVertexPopup(vertexMenu);
        gm.remove(gm.getPopupEditingPlugin());  // Removes the existing popup editing plugin
        gm.add(myPlugin);   // Add our new plugin to the mouse
        this.setGraphMouse(gm);
    }
}
```

After you have compiled this class you can drag it from the Projects window  onto the Netbeans design for your JPanel.